# Jest: mock RxJs pipe

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, jestjs, ngrx

How to mock more complex RxJs behavior (in a context of NgRx)?

Given a simple component (SomeComponent):

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  foo$: Observable<any>;
  bar$: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private store: Store<State>) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.foo$ = this.store.pipe(select(getFooSelector));
    this.bar$ = this.store.pipe(select(getBarSelector));
  }
}
```

I would like to mock store in a way that:

- Based on a passed selector the mock store returns a different value.
- Spy what argument (selector) was passed to the `select` operator.

#### Based on a passed selector the mock store returns different value

I would see it as something like that:

```
store.pipe = jest.fn(selectOperator => {
  switch (selectOperator.arguments[0]) {
    case getFooSelector:
      return foo;
    case getBarSelector:
      return bar;
  }
}
```

#### Spy what argument (selector) was passed to `select` operator.

Something along those lines:

```
const spy = jest.spyOn(store, 'pipe');
expect(spy.mock.calls[0]).toHaveBeenCalledWith(select(getFooSelector));
expect(spy.mock.calls[1]).toHaveBeenCalledWith(select(getBarSelector));
```

#### Summary

I know both of those examples are pseudo codes but I hope they demonstrate what I am trying to achieve. If my approach is completely wrong that please do comment on that.

Comment: There's an ongoing discussion on Ngrx repo to try to have an official support for testing things like that. Not done yet but I've posted what I use right now. I'm using jasmine, not Jest but it might help you build an equivalent : https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/915#issuecomment-414601899

Comment: Thank you for the reference. Sadly I could get any of them to work properly. Your example gives me: InvalidPipeArgument: 'function ...' for AsyncPipe

Answer (score 4):

Use [RxJs Marbles](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjs-marbles) for testing RxJs with NgRx.

For more information read [RxJS Marble Testing: RTFM](https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-marble-testing-rtfm-a9a6cd3db758) and look [Jest Testing - Jesse Sanders](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d91uDEmbBUs), [Reactive Testing Strategies with NgRx - Brandon Roberts & Mike Ryan](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=2520&v=MTZprd9tI6c)

For implementation use [jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#mock-implementations)

```
store.pipe = jest.fn()
   .mockImplementationOnce(foo)
   .mockImplementationOnce(bar)

expect(store.pipe).toHaveBeenCalledWith(select(getFooSelector));
expect(store.pipe).toHaveBeenCalledWith(select(getBarSelector));
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Sadly it does not work for me. I am getting that it expected `Function selectOperator` but got... `Function selectOperator`. Also if I understand your answer correctly there is no easy way of switching results. It strongly relies on an order in which `store.pipe` was called.

Answer (score 1):

With NGRX v8.6.0 you should be able to do something like this:

```
let fixture: ComponentFixture<SomeComponent>;
let mockStore: MockStore<State>;

beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [provideMockStore()],
        declarations: [SomeComponent],
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SomeComponent);
    mockStore = TestBed.get(Store);
    fixture.detectChanges();
});

it('should have a value of foo', done => {
    mockStore.overrideSelector(getFooSelector, 'foo');

    foo$.subscribe(res => {
        done();
        expect(res).toBe('foo');
    });
});

it('should have a value of bar', done => {
    mockStore.overrideSelector(getBarSelector, 'bar');

    bar$.subscribe(res => {
        done();
        expect(res).toBe('bar');
    });
});
```

https://ngrx.io/guide/store/testing